# Python : Postfix stdin

Tags: python, stdin, postfix-mta

I want to make postfix send all emails to a python script that will scan the emails.

However, how do I pipe the output from postfix to python ?

What is the stdin for Python ?

Can you give a code example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To push mail from postfix to a python script, add a line like this to your postfix alias file:

```
# send to emailname@example.com
emailname: "|/path/to/script.py"
```

The [python `email.FeedParser` module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html) can construct an object representing a MIME email message from stdin, by doing something like this:

```
# Read from STDIN into array of lines.
email_input = sys.stdin.readlines()

# email.FeedParser.feed() expects to receive lines one at a time
# msg holds the complete email Message object
parser = email.FeedParser.FeedParser()
msg = None
for msg_line in email_input:
   parser.feed(msg_line)
msg = parser.close()
```

From here, you need to iterate over the MIME parts of `msg` and act on them accordingly.  Refer to [the documentation on `email.Message` objects](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html) for the methods you'll need.  For example `email.Message.get("Header")` returns the header value of `Header`.

Comment: problem now is, I want this to happen for every email, not only the emaildomains that are present. Is there a wirldcard for all domains ?

Comment: @LucasKauffman That's a postfix configuration question. Probably best to ask on serverfault.com, as I don't have an answer.

Comment: Also, you may need to invoke the python interpreter like this: `emailname: "|python path/to/script.py"`.  At least that's what we had to do on othello.

Comment: @swandog lulz.. Hopefully you aren't troubleshooting my old code

Answer (score 12):

Rather than calling `sys.stdin.readlines()` then looping and passing the lines to `email.FeedParser.FeedParser().feed()` as suggested by Michael, you should instead pass the file object directly to the email parser.

The standard library provides a conveinience function, [`email.message_from_file(fp)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_file), for this purpose. Thus your code becomes much simpler:

```
import email
msg = email.message_from_file(sys.stdin)
```